# Tshark crashes silently on the first received packet randomly (linux)

Tags: crash, tshark

I have a custom sniffer, which produces output in pcapng format. I launch it like that:

```
<sniffer launch line> | tee out.pcapng | tshark -Tpdml -i -
```

expecting to have a pdml output in stdout. Generally it works, but sometimes the following happens: after the first packet was written to stdout by sniffer, tshark just reports `0 packets captured` and closes. At the same time the `out.pcapng` appears to be valid and successfully can be opened with wireshark.

Moreover, when I try `cat out.pcapng | tshark -Tpdml -i -`, it would handle the input successfully in 90% of launches, but would still fail sometimes.

It seems, that changing tshark flag from -i to -r helps, but I'm not sure if it solves the problem or just make it appear less often. And anyway, I'd be pleased to know what actually happens there. Launching tsahrk with `stdbuf -o 0 tshark ...` doesn't help.

An example of problematic .pcapng file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GS41yti0zs5-ZT5bgRNYslIQW1q_fDfQ/view?usp=sharing

Version of Tshark: `TShark (Wireshark) 3.2.3 (Git v3.2.3 packaged as 3.2.3-1)`

Comment: I'm unable to download and test the capture file at the moment, but I would suggest trying again with the latest stable version of `tshark`, currently 3.4.7.  If you still experience the same problems, then you may want to consider opening a [Wireshark Issue](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues) for this problem and attaching the problematic capture file.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard Thank you for the answer. The 3.4.7. version of tshark behaves just the same. Yeah, probably opening an issue would be the way... However it is hard to reproduce the issue with the file, it is much more noticable in the live capture mode

Comment: Seemed to be some kind of bufferization problem, adding `stdbuf  -o 0` before each command solved the issue (looks like so)